# awk print output on same line

Tags: linux, awk

I am counting nucleotides in the contigs of a fasta file. My file looks like

```
    >1
    ATACCTACTA
    ATTTACGTCA
    GTA
    >2
    ATATTCGTAT
    GTCTCGATCT
    A
    >3
```

etc.

My command is

```
awk '/^>/ {if (seqlen){print seqlen}; print ;seqlen=0; } { seqlen += length($0)}END{print seqlen}'
```

The output is now like

```
>1
23
>2
21
```

How to get the output on the same line, like

```
>1 23
>2 21
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and more few changes and voila (thanks to @Ed Morton):

```
awk '/^>/ {if(seqlen)print k,seqlen; seqlen=0; k=$0; next;} { seqlen += length($0);}END{print k,seqlen;}' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me:

```
awk '/^>/ && NR>1 {printf " %d \n", x; }/^>/{ printf "%s", $0 }!/^>/{ x += length($0) } file
```

I hope it works now as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did not mention my question with the correct example. I do not want to count only each line, but the lines between the character ">", I have edit my question. The awk command that I use works correct for that, but now I want the output on the same line as the input >.  With your solution, it counts only the lines, but I need to count all lines from the line with >  to the next.

Comment: @Gravel: check now, I updated my answer now, let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
awk '/^>/{printf("%s ",$0);getline;printf("%s\n",length($0))}'   Input_file
```

Checking if a line is starting from > then printing that line now using getline to jump to next line. printing the length of current line with new line, mentionint the Input_file then.

**EDIT:**

```
awk '/^>/{if(VAL){print Q OFS VAL;Q=VAL="";Q=$0;next};Q=$0;next} {VAL=VAL?VAL+length($0):length($0)} END{print Q,VAL}'   Input_file
```

Checking if any line starting from > then checking if VAL variable is NOT NULL if not then print variable Q's and VAL's value and then nullify then Q,VAL variables and next will skip all further statements else make Q as $0 and use next to skep further statements. So creating a variable named VAL which will calculate the length of each line and add to it's own value. in END section print values of Q, VAL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did not mention my question with the correct example. I do not want to count only each line, but the lines between the character ">", I have edit my question. The awk command that I use works correct for that, but now I want the output on the same line as the input >. With your solution, it counts only the lines, but I need to count all lines from the line with > to the next